# image processing, get pure edges

Tags: python, opencv

I am a beginner in python programming and I am asking for some tips. I have a diagram by which I would like to detect edges and then filter to get only clean edges. Can anyone help how I can write python code to go through the rest of the diagram?
I used a Sobel filter for edge detection, but I don't know how to approach a median filter with neighborhood

[image]

pxq with the condition p >> q and p << q.

Here is my code in python:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('original_image.jpg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ddepth = -1

sobelX = cv2.Sobel(img, ddepth ,1, 0, ksize=3,borderType=cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)

sobelY = cv2.Sobel(img, ddepth, 0, 1, ksize=3,borderType=cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)

mag = np.hypot(sobelX, sobelY)

mag = mag / mag.max() * 255

mag = np.uint8(mag)

theta = np.arctan2(sobelY, sobelX)

angle = np.rad2deg(theta)
```

I don't understand the next step:

Apply median filter with neighborhood pxq (p>>q) and (p<<q)

Can someone explain to me in a simple way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it means the median filter with non-square kernel. In OpenCV [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga564869aa33e58769b4469101aac458f9) is mentioned that kernel should be `ksize × ksize` (square), scipy [realization](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.median_filter.html) allows non-square filter shape - so you can use it. (As Mark mentioned)

So if you use say filter size of 1x10, you filter in the horizontal direction.
If filter shape is 10x1, than in vertical.

Here is the explanation:

[image: median filtering]

Comment: It works and there is an effect that reduces the amount of edges. I think about the next steps according to the diagram above, which will leave me pure edges. Because i want to measure the edges transition in the final stage to calculate its sharpness. Is it good idea to use numpy function np.where() to find right cordination of edges on image to find segment of edges and reduce their length?

Answer (score 3):

I presume your professor is trying to differentiate between horizontal and vertical edges but hasn't explained it too clearly.

If I start with this image, and ignore the Sobel stuff since it is already effectively edges:

[image]

```
from skimage.filters.rank import median
import cv2

# Load image and greyscale it
im = cv2.imread('radial.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Define a 25x1 and a 1x25 footprint for the median function
footprintA = np.ones((1,25), np.uint8)
footprintB = footprintA.reshape(-1,1)

# Apply each to image
resA = median(im, footprintA)
resB = median(im, footprintB)
```

[image]

[image]

---

Here is a little animation showing the effect of the footprint shape:

[image]

---

I used **scikit-image** because I don't know how you make a non-square footprint with **OpenCV**.